# How do I set a div to be directly below an element that it doesn't follow directly in the html code?

Tags: html, css, web

Say for example I have a paragraph of text, and when I click on a certain word in a span, I'd like a picture to appear while the word is STILL visible (position the picture right below the word). I know how to do this easily if the the img tag follows the span directly, with relative positioning, but because I have an entire paragraph of text following that one span, I can't put the  in there. Example: (hover over the bold)

```js
function showCat(){
 var y = document.getElementsByClassName("popupImage");
 y[0].style.visibility = "visible";
 //this or something else?
 y[0].style.top = "-2em";
}
```

```css
.popupImage{
width: 40%;
visibility: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 4em;

}
.moreInfo{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id = "bio">I'm John Doe, a <span class ="moreInfo" id="degree" onmouseover="showCat()">HTML and CSS Student</span><br>I chose the HTML/CSS dual degree and moved here in 2016 to get a taste of both disciplines from the <span >University of NoWhere.</span> </p> 

<img class = "popupImage" src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"/>
```

The image cannot fall directly after the span in bold.

I don't do much work at all with frontend design and my instincts tell me there is someway to make the image relative to the span even though they are not one after another in the html.

Answer (score 1):

Your code already showcases the image below the ext in question, but if you want it to appear **next** to the text in question, why not simply move the `<img>` tag to directly after your `<span>` tag? That way you also don't have to worry about `top` positioning:

```js
function showCat() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("popupImage");
  y[0].style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
.popupImage {
  width: 40%;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.moreInfo {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="bio">I'm John Doe, a
  <span class="moreInfo" id="degree" onmouseover="showCat()">HTML and CSS Student</span>
  <img class="popupImage" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
  <br> I chose the HTML/CSS dual degree and moved here in 2016 to get a taste of both disciplines from the
  <span>University of NoWhere.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Obsidian ,  Instead of using `visibility`, you should use `display`

```js
function showCat() {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName("popupImage");
  y[0].style.display = "block";}
```

```css
.popupImage {
  width: 40%;
  display: none;
  position: relative;

}
.moreInfo {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p id="bio">I'm John Doe, a
  <span class="moreInfo" id="degree" onmouseover="showCat()">HTML and CSS Student</span>
  <img class="popupImage" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" />
  <br> I chose the HTML/CSS dual degree and moved here in 2016 to get a taste of both disciplines from the
  <span>University of NoWhere.</span>
</p>
```